# How to use HoughLinesP to detect horizontal lines in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I am currently trying to detect horizontal-like lines in an image using HoughLinesP function in opencv, using these parameters:

`HoughLinesP(linMat[i], lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 80, linMat[i].cols*(0.3), 3);`

where `linMat[i]` is the input image. The result is like this

http://postimg.org/image/49b8wzlgz/

While this is OK, what I want is to have lines in horizontal direction, as shown by the yellow line in this image (the line is manually drawn)

http://postimg.org/image/rh9wlueo7/

I've tried to change the `CV_PI/180` parameter to smaller value (such as `CV_PI/45`) and also try to use various values for other parameters, but the horizontal line cannot be generated.

What values shall be used in the parameters to generate such yellow line using HoughLinesP function in opencv?

Thanks!

**Update**

Following the suggestions (thanks all!) I've tried even very extreme values like

`HoughLinesP(linMat[i], lines, 1, CV_PI/360, 80, 1, 1);`

nevertheless, the resulted lines have slope in near vertical direction as this : postimg.org/image/y5w6vm7lx/ (please copy-paste the link...).
I don't use edge detection filter such as canny since it failed to detect thicker lines, the edges tend to be discontinued lines.

**Update 2**

Just for clarification, the lines drawn in the result are generated as follows (after the HoughLinesP)

`for all lines`

`{`

`line( linMat[i], Point(lines[j][0], lines[j][1]), Point(lines[j][2], lines[j][3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 1, 8 );`

`}`

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the equation

```
double Angle = atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180.0 / CV_PI;
```

Check angle for each line detected by  HoughLinesP(), and consider the lines which has angle 0 or 180.

Comment: As I mentioned in the updated question, it seems that no matter how much I change the angle, the resulted lines are always have vertical slope. Could it be the limitation of the HoughLinesP function for such case?

Answer (score 2):

Try applying Hough on edge-output images of canny or any other algorithm than running it on a thresholded image.

[image]

It could be seen that higher theta values will only represent the horizontal values. Filter out the results obtained in `lines` by eliminating values with low theta values.

Comment: If you set theta to PI you will get almost just vertical lines as result. PI/3 seems to work the same. But PI/6 returns all directions. I have not figured out the details, why it's working this way, but modifying theta on a test picture can give you the directions.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can read in the documentation [(link)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlinesp#cv2.HoughLinesP), I think that the function `HoughLinesP` will detect *all* the lines in your image. The parameters are only thresholds influencing the sensitivity of the detection.

So if you only want the horizontal lines, just filter out the other ones by analyzing the output array. Since each item of the output vector is a 4-element vector `(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)`, you can compute the slope of the line and use it to filter out non-horizontal lines.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can try:

```
for all lines:
  if abs(lines[j][1] - lines[j][3]) == 0:
     # Horizontal line
```

Moreover, if your lines are inclined you can try with:

```
for all lines:
  if abs(lines[j][1] - lines[j][3]) < 20: # Tune this parameter
     # Horizontal line
```

I think you get the idea!

Answer (score 1):

Put `CV_PI/2` (`numpy.pi/2` in Python) as parameter *theta* and it will only scan in 90° steps. This reduces the number of undesired results to filter out as you now have only exactly horizontal and exactly vertical lines in the result. This will also avoid erroneous detecting of slopes in thicker lines when not using edge detection.

Note: Stepping in 180° steps (using `CV_PI` or `numpy.pi`) will deliver vertical lines only.